# I want to calculate time in Asia/Dubai timezone from the time of Asia/Kolkata using java 8 Date Time API

Tags: java, java-8

```
 ZoneId dubai = ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai");
 LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now();
 LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now();
 ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(localDate, localTime, dubai);
System.out.println("Dubai Tiime:"+zonedDateTime);
```

Above code is still printing the time of my current zone (i.e Asia/Kolkata)

Also i tried the following code to achieve the same but it is also printing time in my current zone(Asia/Kolkata):

```
ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.of("+04:00");
LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
OffsetDateTime plusFour = OffsetDateTime.of(localDateTime, offset);
System.out.println("Dubai Time :"+plusFour);
```

I am unable to figure out why its not providing desired result.

Answer (score 4):

The [answer by Kokorin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36707942/642706) is correct. Here's a bit more discussion.

## Problems

When you called the `now` method and passed no arguments, you failed to specify a time zone. In that omission, java.time silently applied your JVM’s current default time zone in determining the current local time and current local date.

You claim your JVM’s current default time zone is `Asia/Kolkata` (India time). If when you ran that code it was 15:30 time in your office, your code is saying “let's take my 15:30 and use that as input to represent a [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time) in Dubai”. So while the current moment in Dubai was actually 14:00 (an hour and half closer to UTC than India I presume, not sure), you created a date-time for an hour and a half in the Dubai’s future: 15:30.

When you passed `dubai` in the line `ZonedDateTime.of( localDate, localTime, dubai )` you assumed you were asking for an *adjustment* between time zones. But in fact you were *assigning* a time zone to a plain (“Local”) date and time that *had no time zone at all*. All three of the **`Local…` classes store no time zone internally**; their very purpose is to ignore time zone. Your code did not match your intentions.

Note how in this revision to your code I pass your [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) object to both `now` methods. This would solve your problem.

```
    ZoneId dubai = ZoneId.of ( "Asia/Dubai" );
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now ( dubai );  
    LocalTime localTime = LocalTime.now ( dubai ); // Capturing `14:00` in Dubai rather than than `15:30` in India as in your version of code.
    ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of ( localDate , localTime , dubai );
    System.out.println ( "Dubai Tiime:" + zonedDateTime );
```

But this is still bad code. If those pair of `.now` methods were called over the stroke of midnight, you would have very wrong information (off by about 24 hours).

## Solutions

Instead you should capture the current moment atomically. Either user Kokorin's code, or use my code shown next.

An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
ZoneId zoneId_Dubai = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Dubai" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Dubai = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId_Dubai );
```

As a shortcut, call the static method [`ZonedDateTime.now`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#now-java.time.ZoneId-).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_Dubai = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId_Dubai );
```

To see the same moment but with your own [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall_clock_time), adjust into [India time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Standard_Time).

```
ZonedDateTime zdt_Kolkata = zdt_Dubai.withZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) );
```

**BIG TIP:** *Always pass the optional time zone arguments*. While I tremendously respect the work that went into java.time, I consider making the time zone arguments optional on various methods to be a design flaw. The silent implicit application of your JVM’s current default time zone is just too easy a trap to fall into for so many programmers. By the way, ditto for [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html), always specify.

**Another Tip:** *Think, work, and store in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).* As a programmer you must learn to think in UTC, get your head out of “my time in Kolkata” and “their time in Dubai”. You will drive yourself crazy and make your brain hurt. While programming, know that **the only one true time is UTC**. All the other Dubai/Kolkata/Montréal/Auckland times are smoke and mirrors, mere illusions. Use the `Instant` class in much of your code, make it your “go to” class when doing date-time work (only apply a time zone for display to the user). Use UTC in your database. Do your logging in UTC. Keep your servers on UTC (or Iceland) time zone. Use UTC when serializing date-time values to storage or in data-exchange (and use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats btw). Keep a clock on your desk or screen displaying UTC. Later, when you go home from work, then you can slip back into your own local "India time" thinking.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you instantiate ZonedDateTime with your **local** date and time.

This will do what you want:

```
ZonedDateTime dubaiDT = Instant.now().atZone(dubaiZone);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. It is working.
Please also tell me what is the use of sending time and zone in ZonedDateTime.of() method?
I referred the document and i thot it is used to convert a given time to the time of a desired timezone.!

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now().withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai"));
```

OUTPUT: **2023-06-20T16:54:11.164069300+04:00[Asia/Dubai]**