# not getting Dubai current time from calendar instance by using Dubai timezone

Tags: android, calendar, timezone, android-calendar, android-date

I have written a code to get Dubai current time. But i am getting the system current time in return

below is the code that i have been using

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone(Asia/Dubai)).getTime();
cal.getTime();
```

cal.getTime() always returns system time.

I am currently in India. so this calendar instance always returns Indian time.

How can I get the Dubai current time

Comment: you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/36709870/4679107

Comment: @KIRAN CSN i want to use calendar instance itself

Comment: This doesn’t come easy and naturally with the `Calendar` class. It’s poorly designed and now long outdated. Consider throwing it away and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with. Use for example `ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("Asia/Dubai"))`. From the linked original questions see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42217542/5772882) and [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46173735/5772882).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
 Calendar localTime = Calendar.getInstance();



        Calendar time= new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Dubai"));
        time.setTimeInMillis(localTime.getTimeInMillis());
        int hr = time.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int min = time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);


        System.out.println(hours);
```

Comment: still it gives  Tue Dec 31 15:40:11 GMT+05:30 2019  ,which is my current time by using code - new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Dubai")).getTime() @KIRAN CSN

Comment: I checked 2 different timezone it was correct

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
Calendar currentTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        currentTime.set(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET, TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC").getRawOffset());
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, currentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 4);
        Log.d(TAG, "time: " + calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```